# Converting JSON to custom format

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting the following JSON from server:

```
"[{"Apr-2015":"20"},{"Mar-2015":"20"},{"Feb-2015":"20"},{"Dec-2014":"10"},{"Nov-2014":"0"},{"Oct-2014":"10"},{"Jul-2014":"0"},{"Jun-2014":"0"},{"May-2014":"0"}]"
```

I need it to be in the following format:

```
[["Apr-2015",20],["Mar-2015",20],["Feb-2015",20],["Dec-2014",0],["Nov-2014",10],["Oct-2014",10],["Jul-2014",0],["Jun-2014",0],["May-2014",0]]
```

I tried doing this:

```
$.map(JSON.parse(data.d), function (key, value) {
                            var test = key.split(':');
                            return [test[0], test[1]];
                        });
```

But since key is of type [object object] I am not able to do so.
How can I get the result I want?

Comment: if the format is that regular, you could probably get away with simple string operations, e.g. `:` -> `,`, `{"` -> `["`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're treating `{"Apr-2015":"20"}` as a key, which is why it just says `[object object]`. You need to also go through each key.

```js
var json = '[{"Apr-2015":"20"},{"Mar-2015":"20"},{"Feb-2015":"20"},{"Dec-2014":"10"},{"Nov-2014":"0"},{"Oct-2014":"10"},{"Jul-2014":"0"},{"Jun-2014":"0"},{"May-2014":"0"}]';

var converted = JSON.parse(json).map(function(item) {
  return Object.keys(item).reduce(function(list, key) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      list.push(key, item[key]);
    }
    return list;
  }, []);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(converted));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version:

```js
var d = [{"Apr-2015":"20"},{"Mar-2015":"20"},{"Feb-2015":"20"},{"Dec-2014":"10"},{"Nov-2014":"0"},{"Oct-2014":"10"},{"Jul-2014":"0"},{"Jun-2014":"0"},{"May-2014":"0"}];
var a = [];

$.each(d, function(i,row){ var key = Object.keys(row)[0]; a.push([key, row[key]]); });
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```